# Counting word lengths in a string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am using an Oracle regular expression to extract the first letter of each word in a string.  The results are returned in a single cell, with spaces representing hard breaks.  Here is an example...

input:

'I hope that some kind person
browsing stack overflow
can help me'

output:

ihtskp bso chm

What I am trying to do next is count the length of each "word" in my output, like this:

6 3 3

Alternatively, a count of the words in each line of the original string would be acceptable, as it would yield the same result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Count the number of spaces and add one:

```
 select (length(your_col) - length(replace(your_col, ' '))+1) from your_table;
```

It will give you the number of words per line. From there you can get all counts on one line by using listagg function:

```
select LISTAGG(cnt,' ') within group (order by null) from (
select (length(a)-length(replace(a,' '))+1) cnt from (
select 'apa bpa bv' a from dual
union all
select 'n bb gg' a from dual
union all
select 'ff ff rr gg' a from dual))
group by null;
```

Perhaps you also need to split the strings if they contain newlines or are they split already?

Comment: Thanks, but I need each "word" length from my output, not a count of words.  Your suggestion would yield "3" when I need "6 3 3."

Comment: I've updated my answer to include recommendation about listagg. Tell me if yo need support with using it.

Comment: Now with listagg included as well.

Comment: Thank you for the listagg suggestion, I think we're on the right track.  I still need to figure out character length (word length) though, as opposed to word count.  Your example 'apa bpa bv' should output '3 3 2' though, not '3.'  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit my original post but it hasn't appeared, but I figured out a way to solve my issue.  I just decided to break the words into rows, since I know how to character count rows, and then reassembled the character counts into a single cell using listagg:

```
with my_string as (
       select regexp_substr (words,'[0-9]+|[a-z]+|[A-Z]+',1,lvl) parsed
       from (
         select words, level lvl 
         from letters connect by level <= length(words) - length(replace(words,' ')) + 1)
       )

select listagg(length(parsed),' ') within group (order by parsed) word_count 
from my_string
```